# Large data set. Should I use flat files or NoSQL/MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

With my current implementation I have about 80gb worth of data, in yaml format, stored in flat files.  I was wondering if anyone has ever moved to a NoSQL data store with this much content and noticed performance differences.  I am considering implementing MongoDB as an option, but was wondering if anyone has had experience of the pros/cons of doing this?  The data will be primarily read only.

Comment: The main question here is, what you actually want to do with your data: offline analyses, archiving, oltp, ... ?

Comment: its primarily read only data that gets generated from a relational database to  de-normalized files for speed reasons

Comment: that's the source of the data - what's its current use?

Comment: its used to generate html pages, which get cached when they can be